# What's the django way to handle votes on objects?

Tags: django

```
class Survey(models.Model):
  answers = models.ManyToMany('Answer')

class Answer(models.Model):
  answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to display in html a list of answers and their vote count, and have for each of them a simple "+1" button that would increment the `votes` value.

If I had to reinvent the wheel, I would call a view `upvote(answer_id)` that would fetch the answer in the database, increment the votes and save, and also would do the same in javascript to update the corresponding field.

Is there a better way to do this in Django ?

Same question if in the html I allow the user to post a new answer.

Comment: What do you want to do? Update a vote once for all, both server side and client side? Do you use an AJAX call or a http request ?

Comment: ajax call, update a vote on server and client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is a AJAX calls with a JSON response. Then update your DOM with javascript.

This is a dummy example:

Django side:

```
import json

def upvote(request, anwser_id):
   # You shall write a better test
   a = Answser.objects.get(pk=anwser_id)
   a.votes += 1
   a.save()
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
       'count': a.votes,
       'pk': anwser_id
   }, content_type="application/json")
```

Client site (assuming jQuery) - no need to post :

```
$.getJSON('/upvote/' + your_anwser_id + '/')
  .done(function(data) {
    // You've got your response here
    $("YOUR-INPUT-SELECTOR").html(data.count);
  })
  .fail(function(xhr) {
    // Server error
    alert("Error: "+ xhr.responseText);
  });
```

If someone votes between two queries, you'll have the correct anwser. I use that kind of solution for a like/dislike comments voting system.